# How to get DPI value of an image in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, dpi

I am trying to extract the Dpi value of an image Using python in one of my django powered web application.I am using following function to achieve my desired output that is the Dpi value of an image but i am facing an exception.

This is the Function to get DPI value of an Image

```
def get_exif_data(fname):
"""Get embedded EXIF data from image file."""
ret = {}
try:
    img = Image.open(fname)
    if hasattr( img, '_getexif' ):
        exifinfo = img._getexif()
        if exifinfo != None:
            for tag, value in exifinfo.items():
                decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
                ret[decoded] = value
except IOError:
    print 'IOERROR ' + fname
return ret
```

and this is the view where i have used that above function to get the DPI value of an Image.

```
def get_dpi(request,image_id):
    image = get_object_or_404(Photo,pk = image_id)
    img = Image.open(image.photo)


    dpi_info = get_exif_data(img)

    context = RequestContext(request)
    ctx = {'dpi':dpi_info}

    return render_to_response('photo/download_image.html',ctx,context)
```

but i am facing the following exception

[image]

Comment: You should pair down your code to show where, exactly, that error is caused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin, I have to ask why you want the DPI resolution. It's just a tag and doesn't really mean anything unless you are outputing to physical media. A 1000x1000 pixel image can be 10x10 at 100dpi or 100x100 at 10dpi, but it's still exactly the same image. Exactly the same pixels. It's hard to imagine scenarios where `img.size` doesn't give you everything you need.

Having said that, if you want to get the exif tags for resolution try `XResolution` from `PIL.ExifTags`:

```
import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS 

img = Image.open("path/to/.jpg")
info = img._getexif()
exifObj = {}
if info != None:
    for tag, value in info.items():
        decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
        exifObj[decoded] = value
```

`exifObj` now either empty or equals something like:

```
 {'YResolution': (720000, 10000), 'BitsPerSample': (8, 8, 8), 'ImageLength': 713, 'Orientation': 1, 'Copyright': 'Mark Meyer Photography', 'ExifImageWidth': 950, 'ExifImageHeight': 713, 'ColorSpace': 1, 'ResolutionUnit': 2, 'DateTime': '2015:01:30 21:37:51', 'XResolution': (720000, 10000), 'ExifOffset': 296, 'PhotometricInterpretation': 2, 'ExifVersion': '0221', 'Artist': 'MarkM', 'ImageWidth': 950, 'SamplesPerPixel': 3, 'Software': 'Adobe Photoshop CC 2014 (Macintosh)'}
```

DPI is:

```
 exifObj['XResolution'][0]/exifObj['XResolution'][1]
```

72DPI in this case.

It's not clear in your example how you are trying to access the DPI value for the context. You're getting an attribute error, so maybe in your template you are trying to access ctx.dpi or something similar which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but now i am facing the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'` after using your code.probably the error is occurring  in the for loop portion where you have used `info.items()` @MarkM

Comment: @Rego, yes `_getexif()` is not guaranteed to return a value. I've edited the answer to test for this. Again—the DPI is not part of the image data, it's just a tag, so it's not always there especially if something in the pipeline is optimizing images and stripping them of exif data. If this is the case, maybe 72DPI is a safe default.

Comment: It's not working for me bro. It's giving empty results, Is there any way to find dpi of an image using python.

Answer (score -2):

Almost I spend searching 3 hours for this. At last I find it out, how we can find **dpi** of an image or pdf using [**fitz**](https://pypi.org/project/fitz/) library, you can download using this command `pip install PyMuPDF` and `pip install fitz`.

If you want to know more about this process you can check it out  [official documentation](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pixmap.html?highlight=dpi#Pixmap.xres). If you found useful upvote it!

```
def dpi_finder(link : str) -> int: 
  doc = fitz.open(link)      # opening a image or pdf. 
  page = doc.load_page(0)    # getting first page 
  pix = page.get_pixmap()    # getting the pixamp 
  return pix.xres            # it will give the dpi for horizontal resolution
```